# How to connect to Amazon aws instance using mindterm?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just signed up for AWS and would like to [connect to my instance using mindterm as per one of the option in the doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mindterm.html).

But the following step seems impossible:

```
Click A Java SSH client directly from my browser (Java required).
```

because there is no such option to click on.

Is the documentation out of date, or am I missing something?

I am using Chrome on Windows 7. Java is working in Chrome (I had to install Java 32-bit version to make it work).